# Avoid Windows folder listing with ACL

Tags: windows, access-control-list

Is it possible through ACL to prevent a local user account to "dir" the windows folder ?

I tried with "Advanced security settings", but cannot change a thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or deny the NTFS permission called "List Folder Contents"
https://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-advanced.htm

If you can't change then you need to take ownership with an admin account. (local/domain admin)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to prevent using dir then you'd have to disable the command prompt and powershell (which would likewise have a dir alias) access to users. This can be done via GPO. Assuming you just want to modify the ntfs permissions for C:\Windows , default NTFS permissions allow for all users to read and execute and modifying it may have unintended consequences. You can modify the ntfs permissions by right clicking the folder, selecting properties, and then the security tab and clicking modify/edit assuming you have administrator privileges.

Comment: Read and execute is incorrect in this matter. It's list folder contents. Read and execute is for the contents in a file, list folder contents is for a directory listing.

Comment: I did not tell them to remove those permissions, but that the permissions are the default.

Comment: That doesn't matter what you tell, you told him the wrong access control object.

Comment: If someone asked how to Delete C:\ , would you just tell them to run rmdir c:\ without warning them?

Comment: Irrelevant. It's about the entries in the access control list, and which permission you grant or not. If you only remove read and execute on that ACL, I guarantee you i can still do a dir on that folder.

Comment: Yes, which I specified how it could be modified because the questioner does not provide any context as to what they tried or needed. I may not have spoonfed the answer for the specific advanced permission. Both answers were correct.